# Disabling some options in select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<select class="pointSelect" id="mySelect" tabindex="2" name="mySelect">
  <option value="01" selected="selected">Choose Country</option>
  <option>United States</option>
  <option>Canada</option>
  <option>United Kingdom</option>
  <option>Czech Republic</option>
  <option>Any other Country</option>
</select>

<select class="pointSelect" id="mySelect1" tabindex="3" name="mySelect1">
  <option value="nothing" selected="selected">Choose Shipping Options</option>
  <option>Free Shipping</option>
  <option>Registered Airmail</option>
  <option>Express Shipping</option>
</select>
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  debugger;
  var index = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
  $("#mySelect1").find("option:lt("+index+")").attr("disabled","disabled");
  $("#mySelect1").find("option:gt("+index+")").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shels123/w9kqy/14/)

How can i **disable Free Shipping only for "Any other country".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Prop in Jquery to disable the option.If you use attr You cant enable and disable option one more time

```
   $("#mySelect1").prop("disabled", true);
   $("#mySelect").change(function () {
         $("#mySelect1").prop("disabled", (this.value == '01'));
         $("#mySelect1").find("option:eq(1)").prop("disabled", (this.value == 'Any other Country'));
     });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kqy/21/)

### [NEW UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kqy/25/)

Comment: ..Thank you very much...It is working as required....On load how can i disable the "shipping options" files and enable it only if i select a country

Comment: @user3790186 sorry i wrongly understand wait for 2 min

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy ..Thank You very much.. Exactly what i required..Thanks to both Bala and Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: @user3790186 which jquery version you are using ?

Comment: @ Bala Now i am using jquery-1.11.1.min.js..the error is gone..but The Free shipping can be selected for all countries ???

Comment: @user3790186 could you provide your code or make a sample in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use .prop() as shown below(I doubt it will work in IE)

```
$("#mySelect").change(function () {
    var disable = $(this).val() == 'Any other Country';
    $("#mySelect1").find("option:contains(Free Shipping)").prop("disabled", disable);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2u7Cp/).

Another method is to remove the option instead of disabling it [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2u7Cp/2/)

```
$("#mySelect").change(function () {
    var freeShipping = $(this).val() != 'Any other Country';
    if (freeShipping) {
        if (!$("#mySelect1").find("option:contains(Free Shipping)").length) {
            $("#mySelect1 option:first-child").after("<option>Free Shipping</option>");
        }
    } else {
        $("#mySelect1").find("option:contains(Free Shipping)").remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` without value attribute wont work in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For disabling shipping
HTML

```
<select disabled="disabled" class="pointSelect" id="mySelect1" tabindex="3" name="mySelect1">
```

Script

```
 $("#mySelect").change(function () {
    $("#mySelect1").removeAttr("disabled")
    var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    if (text == 'Any other Country') {
        $("#mySelect1").find("option:eq(1)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#mySelect1").find("option").removeAttr("disabled")
    }
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kqy/22/)

Comment: Sorry, it is not working..Free shipping is disabled for all options

Answer (score 0):

Use the following before the change function:

```
$("#mySelect option:last").prop('disabled','disabled');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kqy/17/)